# MVC Route not being used when it should

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am working on an application where I would like a url like so `User\1\Class\Create` would map to the Class controller and the Create action, but when I apply it, it doesn't pick it up.

Below is how I have the route registered (it is at the top of the list):

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UserClass",
            url: "User/{userId}/Class/Create",
            defaults: new { controller = "Class", action = "Create", userId= "" },
            constraints: new { userId= @"\d+" }
            );
```

(I have also tried it by omitting the `userId=""` default)

This is paired with this code:

```
public class ClassController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Create(int userId)
    {
        var vm = new ClassEditorViewModel
        {
            Class = new Class { UserId = userId },
            ClassEnrollmentStatuses = new SelectList(Db.ClassEnrollmentStatuses.ToList(), "Id", "Name")
        };

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work.  When I use Route Debugger (by Phil Haack) it doesn't use the above route and selects the `{*catchall}` route.

What am I doing wrong with the route configuration to make it not be used?

Comment: What is the order of your routes? Is this route is on the top of default route?

Comment: Are you literally navigating to *User/1/Class/Create* or are you clicking a link that was created.  In the case of the latter, how are you creating the URL?

Comment: @Andrey.Gubal This route is at the top of the list, most specific to least specific is how I order them.

Comment: @asymptoticFault I am literally navigating to the url when it fails

Comment: Interesting, I just tried it and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Justin Hm, should work, as for me. Did you try to write with controller statement: url: "User/{userId}/{Controller}/{Action}".?

Comment: @Andrey.Gubal I just tried with {controller} and it still fails.

Comment: So I deleted the route and re-typed it and now it works...I must have had typed something wrong but "fixed" it when I pasted here...

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the route and re-typing it resolved the issue.